# Invalid argument(s): string is not well-formed UTF-16 and null check used on null value error

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I wrote a piece of code for searching contacts from the user's phone, but it was initially showing a null check on null value error when I tried to access each of the contacts' phone numbers. So then I commented out that part, but now it's giving the Invalid argument(s): string is not well-formed UTF-16 error when I try to display the contact name. How do I resolve it?

Reference:
https://github.com/ahkharsha/pregAthI/blob/main/lib/widgets/home/bottom-bar/contacts/add_contacts.dart

My code:

```
String flattenPhoneNumber(String phoneStr) {
return phoneStr.replaceAllMapped(RegExp(r'^(\+)|\D'), (Match m) {
  return m[0] == "+" ? "+" : "";
});
}

filterContacts() {
List<Contact> _contacts = [];
_contacts.addAll(contacts);
if (searchController.text.isNotEmpty) {
  _contacts.retainWhere((element) {
    String searchTerm = searchController.text.toLowerCase();
    String searchTermFlatten = flattenPhoneNumber(searchTerm);
    String contactName = element.displayName!.toLowerCase();
    bool nameMatch = contactName.contains(searchTerm);
    if (nameMatch == true) {
      return true;
    }
    if (searchTermFlatten.isEmpty) {
      return false;
    }
    var phone = element.phones!.firstWhere((p) {
      String phnFlattened = flattenPhoneNumber(p.value!);
      return phnFlattened.contains(searchTermFlatten);
    });
    return phone.value != null;
  });
}
setState(() {
  contactsFiltered = _contacts;
});
}

fetchContacts() {
getFullContacts();
  searchController.addListener(() {
    filterContacts();
  });
}

getFullContacts() async {
List<Contact> _contacts =
    await ContactsService.getContacts(withThumbnails: false);
setState(() {
  contacts = _contacts;
});
}

....

return ListTile(
                            title: Text(contact.displayName??'Phone contact ${index+1}'),
                            // subtitle:
                            //     Text(contact.phones!.elementAt(0).value!),
                            leading: contact.avatar != null &&
                                    contact.avatar!.length > 0
                                ? CircleAvatar(
                                    backgroundColor: primaryColor,
                                    backgroundImage:
                                        MemoryImage(contact.avatar!),
                                  )
                                : CircleAvatar(
                                    backgroundColor: primaryColor,
                                    child: Text(contact.initials()),
                                  ),
                            onTap: () {
                              if (contact.phones!.length > 0) {
                                final String phoneNumber =
                                    contact.phones!.elementAt(0).value!;
                                final String Name = contact.displayName!;
                                _addContact(TContact(phoneNumber, Name));
                              } else {
                                Fluttertoast.showToast(
                                    msg: "Phone number does not exist..");
                              }
                            },
                          );
                        },
                      ),
```